# Why Laravel collections do not support all PHP operators?

Tags: laravel, collections

```
 $collection = collect([
    ['product' => '1', 'price' => 1],
    ['product' => '2', 'price' => 2],
    ['product' => '3', 'price' => 3],

]);
print $collection->where('price', '&', 1)->pluck('product')->implode(', ');
```

It prints 1. But must print 1, 3.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c6cf38139d2524a7c3accb606e3fb1b035c98d6a/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php#L890

Why Laravel collections do not support all PHP operators?

Comment: because there is no need to, as you can use `filter`(which is what `where` calls) and do what you want in it ... `where` is just a convenience to using `filter` and is for basic comparisons

Comment: I understand that I can do it in many other different ways. However, I completely disagree that it no need. In such logic, method where no need, because we can use filter instead.

Comment: you can disagree with what ever you like ... have a nice day